# Renewed code signing certificate does not work

Tags: java, applet, code-signing-certificate, jarsigner

I had a Code signing certificate from GoDaddy which expired back in February, and I used it to sign JAVA jar files, copied it to an ftp server
and ran them as applets. Everything worked fine.

In January I made a renewal for one year.

Despite the fact, that I made what was suggested in the GoDaddy guide (downloaded the zip file, extracted it, and imported it in the keystore)
it was not working, when signing the jar file it still gave me the warning, that my certificate will expire in six months.

So I decided to re-key my certificate, and followed exactly the steps from GoDaddys website:
First, I made a new keystore, to have a fresh start:

```
keytool -genkey -alias sboda -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks
```

then I entered the needed information, like name, organization, etc.
and generated the CSR file

```
keytool -certreq -alias sboda -file file.csr -keystore keystore.jks
```

After this, I copy pasted the CSR into the  CSR box on the website, and asked for rekey.

Downloaded and extracted ZIP file, imported it to the newly created keystore with

```
keytool -importcert -file filename.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

I trusted the certificate, and the certificate was imported.
I signed the jar with

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore ./keystore.jks -tsa http://tsa.starfieldtech.com/ ~/workspace/example.jar sboda
```

it gave me the warning:
Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.

I copied the jar file to the server, and gave this error, when I try to launch the applet:

[image]

The other applets, that were signed earlier, are working fine...
Did I miss anything?

Already contacted GoDaddy support two times, but they were not really helpful, so I thought I also ask here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime I figured it out, thanks to other vendors documentation.
Instead of

```
keytool -importcert -file filename.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

use

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias alias -file filename.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

hopefully other will not stumble into this problem, I lost half a day with it.

Comment: did you have to start the whole process over again?  I'm in the same boat as you and would hate to have to go through the process of re-sending a CSR to godaddy over this.  Actually on the phone with them right this moment

Comment: @Matt sorry, I was on holidays, I hope that you managed in the meantime. If not, no, you do not have to go through the whole process again, just from the part when you download the zip files...

Comment: yeah, thanks.  I don't remember what the steps were from where I posted that comment but I did end up getting it squared away.